# Make materials colors show on textured solid?

Tags: uv, 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine, image

In solid mode with textured solid checked, A model will show the material color until any face on the model is "attached to an image" (have the face selected, and open an image in the UV image editor). The model will then turn white. Is there any way to revert this? I'm using internal.

[image]

Here we are in textured solid mode. The green cube has a green material. I selected the green cube, enter edit mode, select a face, then change the image in the UV image editor. A UV map that I never created appears, and the cube  turns white:

[image]

How can I make it green again while still showing the texture on the checkered cube

Comment: Are you using blender internal or cycles?

Comment: Please include  screen images to increase clarity.

Comment: Once you have UVs the object color will be ignored in the viewport, I think you can achieve that only in textured shading

Comment: the other faces has no texture to a color from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Consider Delete the UV Map
- Add a new UV Map if desired
- Assuming the first UV Map was a quick and easy inspection
- Please note that the Blender User can have multiple 3D View type windows.  Not all windows are simultaneously affected by this inconvenience.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms once you select an image it will be created

Comment: @Chebhou just noticed, *facepalm*, that was so obvious! I never knew blender would make a UV map simply because I changed the image in the UV image editor...

Answer (score 0):

It's a little strange but, as you have discovered: selecting an image in the uv editor dropdown *while in edit mode with one or more faces selected* is the mechanic for assigning an image to those face(s).

And when the object owning the selected faces has no uvmap, the above operation forces a new one to be made. In a "blank", new uvmap, *every* quad is mapped to the entire 0,0->1,1 UV space. Not sure what the defaults are for other poly types.

It could be argued that in textured solid a face with a uvmap but no image should fall back to the material; it's certainly possible to have a uvmap on an object just to control a procedural material's scale and warp; I usually use a set of colored test grids for that personally, but they mean nothing to the render.